# Can I host Azure App Services on the VMs that I have reserved?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice

If have reserved few VMs in Azure, can't I use them to host App services? The instance types I see in VMs is not same as the ones I see in App Service?

For the reserved EC2 instances in AWS, I am able to use them by Elastic Beanstalk service. Isn't the same option available in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the [Azure app servic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview)e is multiple-tenant PaaS. There are multiple web apps that will host the same [app service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans) and you don't need to manage the underlying infrastructure for your hosting web apps.

Alternatively, you could directly host your application on the Azure VMs or Azure VM scale sets that make you more control of the infrastructure. Also, you could refer to [load-balancing options in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/load-balancing-overview).